# How to insert a documents in bulk in Couchbase?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

I didn't see any way to insert documents in bulk using Couchbase Python client. Any example of how to insert documents in bulk using REST api?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering here for Couchbase only, as you probably know they are 2 different project with different features.

The Python SDK does not have a way to bulk load the data.

So to do that you can use:
- the standard set/add methods
- the cbdocloader command line tool that allows you to inject data from the file system into Couchbase Server see : http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbdocloader.html

Answer (score 0):

I used a CURL script with the Sync Server RESTful API
Example JSON as 400001.json file belonging to sync user1.

```
    {"type": "task-list", "name": "Order400001", "owner": "user1", "_id" : "user1.S100400001" 
,
"Order": {
        "OrderID": "S100400001",
        "Status": "In Transit",
        "Customer": "My Customer",
        "DateSubmitted": "12/21/2017",
        "PO": "123455",
        "SoldToAccount": "0001122333",
        "ShipToAccount": "0001122333",
        "Items": [{
                "ItemID": "XXX",
                "ItemStatus": "In Transit",
                "ItemQty": "2",
                "ItemPrice": "1500",
                "ItemDescription": "MODULE XXX US CAN"
            },
            {
                "ItemID": "XXXG",
                "ItemStatus": "In Transit",
                "ItemQty": "2",
                "ItemPrice": "15000",
                "ItemDescription": "MODULE XXX US CAN (GOLD)"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then the script like this

curl -X POST "http://user:password@MyCouchBaseSyncServerHost:4984/orders/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic {your key here}" -d @401000.json